# How to get the current free disk space in Bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, diskspace

I'm running some operations which constantly eat up my disk space. For this reason I want my computer to make a sound when disk space is running below 2GB. I know I can get an output listing the free diskspace by running `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                                      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                                     112Gi  100Gi   12Gi    90%  26291472   3038975   90%   /
devfs                                          191Ki  191Ki    0Bi   100%       663         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                                       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /home
```

but I can't use this output in an if-then statement so that I can play a sound when the Available free space drops below 2GB.

Does anybody know how I can get only the Available space instead of this full output?

Answer (score 9):

This was the only portable way (Linux and Mac OS) in which I was able to get the amount of free disk space:

```
df -Pk . | sed 1d | grep -v used | awk '{ print $4 "\t" }'
```

Be aware that `df` from Linux is different than the one from Mac OS (OS X) and they share only a limited amount of options.

This returns the amount of free disk space in *kilobytes*. Don't try to use a different measure because they options are not portable.

Answer (score 4):

First, the available disk space depends on the partition/filesystem you are working on. The following command will print the available disk space in the current folder:

```
TARGET_PATH="."
df -h "$TARGET_PATH"  | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'
```

`TARGET_PATH` is the folder you are about writing to. `df` automatically detects the filesystem the folder belongs to.

Comment: Dropping `-h` from `df` options would help here: `df . | awk 'NR==2{if($4<=2*1024*1024) print "Available space < 2 GB\a"}'`

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't saw the `> 2GB` restriction .

Comment: Or even `$ df --output=avail . | awk 'NR==2 && $0 <= 2 * 2**20 { print "Available space <= 2 GB\a" }'`.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
Check_space() { 
    set -e
    cd
    Home=$PWD
    reqSpace=100000000
    SPACE= df "$Home"
    if [[ $SPACE -le reqSpace ]]
    then
    $SPACE
    echo "Free space on  " 
    fi
}
Check_space
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.